# I want both implementations of __builtin_popcountll

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, bit-manipulation, clang, instructions

I have some code that I'd like to run the fast built-in CPU instruction `popcnt` (when `__builtin_popcountll` is compiled using proper flags such as with `g++ -mpopcnt` or `clang++ -march=corei7`, this happens), but also be able to fall-back to code when `cpuid` reveals a CPU not supporting the HW instruction.

Of course, to get the fall-back code that I trust the compiler folks have implemented right (so I don't have to bring in C or asm code to do my popcount) I need a separate compilation unit that is compiled without the `-mpopcnt` or `-march=corei7` flags.

Is linking together separately compiled code the only way? Are there no compiler intrinsics or other types of hints or other built-ins I don't know about that I can use to have it generate the fallback popcount code?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure, but the cost of putting in code necessary to select between the popcnt instruction and a fallback implementation might have a larger performance hit than simply going with a non-popcnt implementation all of the time.

To switch in an alternate implementation (doing the switching at the site of the popcnt), you will need at least the following:

- Load and check the cpuid bit (CPUID.01H:ECX.POPCNT[Bit 23])
- Branch to select popcnt or alternate implementation
- Potentially save/restore registers needed for the alternate implementation
- Potentially move data to SIMD registers, if the alternate implementation is SSE or AVX based

I suspect that the cost prohibits an effective implementation of the intrinsic that you describe.

Comment: Hmmm. So, I'd need to do something like "unrolling" the inner loops with the two versions and select from them less dynamically, in order to see a practical benefit to doing this. That's fine, the question is a bit vague and it's really just "how to get this to work", which "it wouldn't be practical" isn't a perfect answer for.

Comment: to be specific: how can I even generate the two alternate implementations (which use the same intrinsic I believe) in the same compilation unit?

Answer (score 1):

gcc has a feature called "multiversioning" specifically for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the "fall back code" directly. I believe it's accessible of the standard libraries as:

```
int __popcountsi2 (int a)
int __popcountdi2 (long a)
int __popcountti2 (long long a)
```